# Why is is RxS an integral domain iff one of R or S is an integral domain, and the other contains only a zero element?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The problem is as stated in the title. It's from "Modern Algebra" by John Durbin. The right to left direction seems straightforward to me.

WLOG, we suppose $R$ is an integral domain, and $S = \{0\}$. Since $R$ is an integral domain, elements of $R$ commute. This means where $(r_0, 0), (r_1,0) \in RxS$, we have (r_0r_1, 0) = (r_1r_0, 0). In other words, $RxS$ commutes. We use similar arguments to prove $RxS$ has no zero divisors, and it has a non-zero identity element.

I can't yet get the other direction, though. The strategy I'm pursuing so far is to assume $RxS$ is an integral domain and then suppose towards a contradiction $R$ and $S$ are integral domains. Once I find a contradiction, I can demonstrate how it's impossible neither of them are integral domains, leaving the possibility only one is.

It seems like both of $R$ and $S$ can be, though. Since $R$ and $S$ commute, $RxS$ would, too. Neither $R$ or $S$ have zero divisors, so neither would $RxS$. The same goes for a non-zero identity element. Where $e_r$ and $e_s$ are the non-zero identities in $R$, $S$, respectively, $(e_r,e_s) \in RxS$. seems to be such an element.

Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Supppse that $R\times S$ is an integral domain.  Suppose on the contrary that neither  $R$ nor $S$ is an integral domain. It follows that there exist zero divisors $r\in R,s\in S$, i.e., there exist $r',s'$ in $R$ and $S$ respectively such that $rr'=0,ss'=0$

$(r,s)(r',s')=(0,0)\implies (r,s)=(0,0)$ or $(r',s')=(0,0)$, which contradicts the definition of zero divisors. It follows that atleast one of $R$ and $S$ is an integral domain.

Suppose, wlog, that $R$ is an integral domain. Note that for any $b\in S$, $(0,b)(1,0)=(0,0)\implies (0,b)=(0,0)\implies b=0$. It follows that $S=\{0\}$.

Also, if $R$ and $S$ both are integral domains then $R\times S$ can't be an integral domain as $(1,0)$ is a zero divisor of $R\times S$.

Answer (score 0):

> Neither $R$ or $S$ have zero divisors, so neither would $RxS$.

This is false. We always have $(r,0)(0,s)=0$. If $R$ and $S$ have more than one element each, this necessarily introduces zero divisors regardless of whether $R$ or $S$ had any initially.

Answer (score 0):

> Neither $R$ or $S$ have zero divisors, so neither would $R\times S$.

Are you sure about that? Consider the product ring $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, and the elements $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Do you see how to generalize this to prove the result in question? *(Think about what exactly we're assuming about $1$, here ...)*

---

Incidentally, there's a fair amount known about what sorts of properties *are* preserved under various operations on structures. For example, **equations** *(= expressions of the form "For all $x_1,...,x_n$ we have $t(x_1,...,x_n)=s(x_1,...,x_n)$" for some terms $t,s$ in the relevant language)* are indeed preserved by direct products, so for example if $R$ and $S$ are commutative rings then $R\times S$ will also be a commutative ring. But "no zero divisors" is a bit more complicated. The relevant subjects here are **universal algebra**, **model theory**, and **category theory**; this is all rather advanced material for the moment, but I think knowing that it exists, even in the abstract, can help you avoid assumptions that properties "lift" from simple structures to complicated ones as has happened here.